# UWSGI Hangs With HTML Form Post

Tags: python, nginx, flask, forms, uwsgi

In Python flask, I created a view using flask.views.MethodView that works if I do not send a form. But if I send a form with xml.send(form) it hangs.

JavaScript call:

```
function jackpot() {
            var form = new FormData();
        var fname = "hello there";
        form.append("filename", fname);
        var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xml.open("POST", "/site/myapp/bob", true);

        console.log("sent")
        xml.onreadystatechange = function () {
            console.log(xml.readyState);
            console.log(xml.status);
            if (xml.readyState == "4" && xml.status == "200"){
                console.log("yes");
                console.log(xml.responseText);
            }
        }
        xml.send(form);
    }
```

Python script:

```
import flask, flask.views
app = flask.Flask(__name__)

class View1(flask.views.MethodView):
    def get(self):
        pass

    def post(self):
        return "hello world"
        #return str(flask.request.form('filename'))

app.add_url_rule('/site/myapp/bob', view_func=View1.as_view('bob'))
```

### Update

I believe the issue is now between nginx and uwsgi.

Output from uwsgi:

```
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 16582)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 16587, cores: 2)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 16589, cores: 2)
spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 16591, cores: 2)
spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 16593, cores: 2)
[pid: 16591|app: 0|req: 1/1] 10.5.46.20 () {48 vars in 884 bytes} [Sat Sep 21 18:02:25 2013] POST /site/myapp/bob => generated 11 bytes in 5 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 2 headers in 79 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 22.22.22.22;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.access_log main;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.error_log info;

location / {
root /var/www/dude;
}

location /site/ {
       try_files $uri @uwsgi;
}

location @uwsgi {
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:3031;
    }

}
```

uwsgi config:

```
one@chat-dash:~$ cat /etc/uwsgi.d/myapp.ini 
[uwsgi]
socket = 127.0.0.1:3031
uid = web
gid = web
plugins = python
chdir = /site
module = myapp
callable = app
pythonpath = /python
processes = 4
threads = 2
#enable-threads = true
#daemonize = /var/log/uwsgi/myapp.log

one@chat-dash:~$
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is hanging here. Flash is correctly returning your response. However your JavaScript is not seeing it, because you are calling `send` before defining the callback, which is the wrong way round.